# how to fire useLayoutEffect after fetching data from an api?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

am fetching some data from an api and am using ref on jsx made from the data of that api. problem is that as you know, uselayouteffect is fired synchronously, therefore it is getting fired before useeffect and it returns error that ref.current is null. I tried using loading state, which is true at the start and am setting it as false when data is fetched from an api but it is not working.
uselayout:

```
 useLayoutEffect(() => { 
      if(!loading){ setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth); }
     
   
      
     }, [language , loading])
```

ref on fetched data:

```
 <span className='big ' id='meria' ref={ref} style={{marginRight:  width / 2    }}>
```

and useEffect:

```
seEffect(() => {
      const link = `mylink`;
     fetch(link)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
  
     
      setMember(data[id-1])
     
    setLoading(false)
    },[])
```

am expecting an aswer from experienced person

Comment: Why don't you use `useEffect` instead?

Comment: because am changing things directly in the jsx, therefore useLayoutEffect is the one.